CMake error finding OpenSSL. "Could NOT find OpenSSL. OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR. missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY. found version "3.0.14""
OS: Windows 11
I am trying to build the AmazonGamelift C++ Server SDK on Windows.
Github: https://github.com/aws/amazon-gamelift-plugin-unreal?tab=readme-ov-file#build-the-amazon-gamelift-c-server-sdk
I run into an issue when I get to the last line of this portion.
mkdir out
cd out
cmake -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -DBUILD_FOR_UNREAL=1 ..
msbuild ALL_BUILD.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Release

It results in the following error.
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22621.0 to target Windows 10.0.22631.
  CMake Error at C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/C
  Make/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
    **Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
    system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY) (found
    version "3.0.14")**
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cm
  ake-3.27/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
    C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cm
  ake-3.27/Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake:668 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
    CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)

"Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR"
This portion of the error sounds straight forward enough, except that I already set that environment variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR.
my environment variable
"(missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY)"
This portion is confusing. It it saying this is part of the problem? Is it a secondary problem in addition to the environment variable?
"(found version "3.0.14")"
This portion is also confusing. It seems contradictory that it both found a version, but also could not find OpenSSL. Is it implying that the version it found is not compatible? That doesn't make sense along side the recommendation of setting the environment variable.
I tried adding various other environment variables.

OPENSSL_CONFG
OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR
OPENSSL_LIBRARIES
OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR

I tried the original installation path of c:\Program Files, as well as just c:\
I found the issue here: How to fix CMake Error Could NOT find OpenSSL missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY when configuring Azerothcore
but downgrading my version to 3.0.14 didn't make a difference.

Downgrading to 1.1.1w resolved the issue for now.
Downloaded here: https://kb.firedaemon.com/support/solutions/articles/4000121705

There's a reason why the date on that 1.1.1 download is Sep 2023 and not June 2024:  OpenSSL 1.1.1 End of Life: "OpenSSL 1.1.1 series has reached its End of Life (EOL). As such it will no longer receive publicly available security fixes."  Whatever code is using OpenSSL needs to be updated to use a supported version so security issues are actually fixed.

Thanks, yeah I should have included that as well, but that is the reason I didn't accept it as the answer for this post. Unreal Engine 5.3 is using an outdated version of OpenSSL, so hopefully they will update it in a future release.
